# Jplayer not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I installed JPlayer (http://www.jplayer.org/) on my restaurant website http://www.amicobio.co.uk/Videos.aspx and it doesn t work in IE.

It doesn t throw any error and I cant see anything wron using the developer toolbar.

Everything looks fine, have you got any idea what's wrong with it?

Funny thing i downloaded the demos and they don't work either............

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your page using Net Tab in Firebug. It seems that the player will only work when the whole movie is downloaded first. that is about 17.7MB

I guess, You would need to tell JPlayer not to preload the file. Try setting '[preload](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-option-preload)' attribute to 'none'.